# Stop Jsoup document toString method from outputting nodes was not in the input string passed to the html parser

Tags: java, html, jsoup, malformed

We use jsoup html parser to parse a malformed document, such as
<div><span>span 1</span><span>span 2</span>

Note that the html document is malformed, missing the trailing </div>.

```js
java code
String destString = "<div><span>span 1</span><span>span 2</span>";
org.jsoup.nodes.Document jDoc = Jsoup.parse(destString, "", Parser.xmlParser());
System.out.println("Parse:" + jDoc.toString());
```

The output will be is
outcome: <div><span>span 1</span><span>span 2</span></div>

Our use case need to preserve the content, unless it is changed by our conversion logic. The addition of trailing "</div>" is considered a bug. How can I override the above behavior

I expect jsoup Document.toString() will not include node that do not exist in the string passed to the html parser.